# Text.Hamlet.Runtime - nesting HamletData?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet, shakespeare-text

I am rendering Hamlet templates using the Runtime module. The following works as promised with the example data:

```
let hamletDataMap = Map.fromList
  [ ("name", "Michael")
  , ("hungry", toHamletData True) -- always True
  , ("foods", toHamletData
    [ "Apples"
    , "Bananas"
    , "Carrots"
    ])
  ]
```

But I can't see any way for me to render nested data. For instance if I have a list of metadata of various fruits, I would like to do something like:

```
let hamletDataMap = Map.fromList
  [ ("name", "Michael")
  , ("hungry", toHamletData True) -- always True
  , ("fruits", toHamletData
    [ [ ("name", "apple")
      , ("taste", "sour")
      ]
    , [ ("name", "..")
      , ("taste", "...")
      ]
    ])
  ]
```

In the `Text.Hamlet.RT` there is the `HDList [HamletMap]` which looks kindof strange but still promising. I can creates instances of `HDList` but it gives me type mismatch `HamletData` with actual type `RT.HamletData url0`.

I'm thankful for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Include the precise code which gives you the error, as well as the error itself.

Comment: I am not asking you to help me fix a compile error, I am asking for suggestions or ideas on how I could go about to pass fields of `[Map Text HamletData]` or other datatype. Possibly I could work something out with list of lists but its not the best solution

Comment: You've mentioned that you found a potential solution but it gave you an error. Instead of asking someone to find a solution for you, you should ask them to help you with your attempt.